# Why all programs in intellij results in class not found error

Tags: java, intellij-idea, concurrency, parallel-processing

So, I was trying to run a source code that I got the [following error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mrpJ.png)

and here is my [directory folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SB5mD.png)
as far as I know there is no problem in defining the name of classes and the directories. 
the code I'm trying to run is an example of Deitel Java how to program.

```
package Concurrency;

import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class SortComparison {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SecureRandom generator = new SecureRandom();

        int[] array1 = generator.ints(15_000_000).toArray();
        int[] array2 = new int[array1.length];
        System.arraycopy(array1, 0, array2, 0, array1.length);

        System.out.println("Starting sort");
        Instant sortStart = Instant.now();
        Arrays.sort(array1);
        Instant sortEnd = Instant.now();

        long sortTime = Duration.between(sortStart, sortEnd).toMillis();
        System.out.printf("Total time in milliseconds: %d%n%n", sortTime);

        System.out.println("Starting parallelSort");
        Instant parallelSortStart = Instant.now();
        Arrays.parallelSort(array2);
        Instant parallelSortEnd = Instant.now();

        long parallelSortTime =
                Duration.between(parallelSortStart, parallelSortEnd).toMillis();
        System.out.printf("Total time in milliseconds: %d%n%n",
                parallelSortTime);

        String percentage = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance().format(
                (double) sortTime / parallelSortTime);
        System.out.printf("%nSort took %s more time than parallelSort%n",
                percentage);
    }
}
```

then I tried to change the JDK version I'm using from version 12 to 11, then the same thing happend to the other projects.

things even get better :))). I tried to create a simple hello world project, then same thing happend there. Is there a problem with Intellij Idea or my java version? right now, I have JDK version 13. Should I reinstall Intellij or there is alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure to build the project before execution Run/Debug Configuration or that Run Configuration has **Make** step in **Before launch** section.
2. Make sure the correct module is specified in the **Use classpath of module** drop-down
3. Check that the [module's compiler output directory](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/specifying-compilation-settings.html#specify_compilation_output_folders) indeed has this compiled class. IDE copies the class there when the project is built.

Answer (score 0):

you probably moved your main class. check your run configuration

Comment: I checked every thing. Even tried to create a hello world project from scratch. Again, the same error